# Where does the _id being generated (and checked)?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

The database action insert now seems to be synchronous returning _id right after the insertion, therefore no callback is needed here.

The question lies on where does the _id being generated (and checked), since this seems to be a fast synchronous action done on miniMongo, yet there is no full list of _id of a certain collection, how’s that possible for miniMongo to check whether the _id is duplicated or not??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `Collection.insert` on the client, the `_id` is generated on the client using a [random uuid algorithm](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L552), hence the seemingly perfectly latency compensated client-side insertion.

`Collection.insert` being implemented as a special case of `Meteor.method`, we know that at the same time the client simulation is run on the client, a corresponding server operation is triggered, the client document is sent to the server along with its locally generated `_id`.

On the server, there's a check to see if the `_id` is correct (truly unique) and the server acknowledge the valid insertion back to the client.

If the client generated `_id` was not unique after all, then the insert will fail with a "duplicate key error" (this could happen like 0.001% of the time - the probability is even lower, and you would have to resubmit your client form or whatever).

To answer specifically your question, the `_id` can be generated in the browser in case of a client insert, but it's validity is ultimately checked on the server.

EDIT : I initially assumed that Meteor was trying to recover from the duplicate key error and generate a new key to avoid duplicity and propagate it on the client, I tested the use case and found out I was wrong, thanks @Tom Freudenberg for pointing this out.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about that sequence? What is about setting the _id directly by myself like: `col.insert({ id: 'mykey', ... });`. This is valid and in that case you got a key violation error. From my point of view, the _id is ALWAYS generated (if not given like above) unique by internal Mongo.ObjectID() method (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id). So I am nearly sure, that never an _id is changed during or after insert once it is specified. If it doesn't fit there is always an error.

Comment: May I ask where did you get this information and really thanks a lot for answering so fast!!

Comment: @Ziac : mainly from reading official Meteor discussion group where MDG would randomly discuss about Meteor internal implementation, also reading directly the source code sometimes.